# Google Script - return ContentService.createTextOutput?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to display a count of the rows in the `return ContentService.createTextOutput()` has that been appended rather than just `"Data Collected Saved"`. Hopefully this is possible?

```
function doPost(e) {
var data = eval(e.postData.contents) ;
var usr = data[0][0];
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sh = ss.getSheetByName(usr) ;
var now = new Date()// Variable for date


if ( sh == null ) { 
    ss.insertSheet(usr);
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName(usr) ;
    var pos = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(usr);
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(pos);
    var sheets = ss.getSheets();
    ss.moveActiveSheet(sheets.length);
    sh.appendRow(["User","Asset ID","Project"]);
    }

for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
sh.appendRow(data[i]);
}

return ContentService.createTextOutput("Data Collected Saved") ;
}
```

Comment: `eval` posted data????? please, no. Use  **`JSON.parse`**

Comment: Signing off - you might want to take a look at why ["never use eval"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!) on MDN

Answer (score 2):

```
return ContentService.createTextOutput("Data Collected Saved " + data.length);
```

[JS Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε what would you suggest?

Comment: Something like "Getting the size of an array in JS means that you want the length of it" maybe also adding a link to a relevant JS doc page like the MDN one? You never know the level of knowledge of your readers, so, assume your are speaking to someone that have a really basic one :)